# WPF MVVM Light Galasoft Upgrade and Messengers are not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, light, messenger

We have a legacy app that uses MVVM Light version 3.X.  We have had looping issues in the application and we want to try upgrading the MVVM Light package to the latest 5.2.  We have a lot of messengers in the application.  Many of them still continue to work as expected, but some do not.  They all register, but some never are listened for, even between the same View Models that have other calls that work.  Anyone experience this issue when upgrading?

Comment: Maybe the listeners get garbage collected before being called?

Comment: I have new code on v5.2 and I cannot get messaging to work outside the WPF executable.  If I register in a dll and send message from exe the message handler is never fired.  Sorry I have no solution but a shared experience.